# Question Regarding the Commutativity of F-Algebras when the Algebra is finite dimensional over F.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $A$ be some $F$-Algebra, for some field $F$, with the property that $A$ is finite dimensional over $F$. Is $A$ always commutative?

Answer (score 5):

Do you know of any noncommutative algebras?

- Matrix algebras: $M_n(F)$ over fields $F$ (when $n>1$). Dimension $n^2$.
- Group algebras $F[G]$ (when $G$ is nonabelian).  Dimension is $|G|$.
- Quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ are noncommutative $\mathbb{R}$-algebras. Dimension is $4$.

These are all associative algebras. (Dietrich gives two canonical examples of nonassociative.)

Answer (score 2):

The definition in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field) allows non-commutative and non-associative algebras over $F$, such as Lie algebras or Jordan algebras. A "motivating" example are also the quaternions, which are anti-commutative.

Comment: Also octonions.